# Dynamically listen on an nginx port

Tags: nginx

I'd like to pass a port to Nginx to listen on dynamically. So I can write something like:

```
PORT=4567 nginx -c $PWD/nginx.conf
```

and then have an nginx config that looks something like:

```
http {
    server {
        listen $PORT;
    }
}
```

and have nginx listen on the specified port. I tried compiling nginx with lua support, and writing:

```
events {
    worker_connections 200;
}

env SERVER_PORT;

http {
    server {
        set_by_lua_block $sp {
            return os.getenv("SERVER_PORT");
        }
        listen $sp;
        root /Users/kevin/code/nginx-testing;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, either; `$sp` doesn't get defined until the `rewrite` phase.

Are there any options here or am I resigned to rewriting the config file via `sed` or similar before starting nginx?

Kevin

Comment: Maybe: PORT=1234\nexport PORT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [listen directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) does not support nginx variable or ENV variable.
So it cannot listen on a nginx port dynamically.

Dynamical listen via ENV variable is technically feasible, you should modify nginx core.
But it cannot be implemented via nginx variable, nginx must listen on some specified port before receiving http requests.
(nginx variable system works on http request.)

---

You can write some script to modify "listen" directive before starting nginx, which is a not-so-good way to implement dynamic listen.

Comment: The listen directive doesn't support env variables. Thanks, but how does your answer solve this problem?

Comment: @DavidVartanianIf you want nginx to support env variable with listen directive, you need to modify the nginx core, letting it support parsing the parameters of `listen` directive to use ENV, but it is not a good way to do this.